# How to debug file upload in Chrome?

Tags: html, debugging, curl, file-upload, google-chrome-devtools

I have tried to debug file upload process in Chrome, but I don't see proper tools for it. I created simple HTML form like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>File upload</h1>
    <form id="upload" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3004/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="upfile" type="file" name="upfile" required >
      <input id="thing" type="hidden" name="thing" value="secret" >
      <button type="submit">up and up!</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I choose file for form input and submit the form, in devtools Network tab I don't see anything about the uploaded file. I have request headers, but no request body, no info about file (except `Content-Length`). I tried to copy request as Curl command, but this also does not have info about file nor the reference to the actual file:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3004/' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: et-EE,et;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 7740' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarye1vOPcczTi7csq6Q' \
  -H 'Origin: null' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="109", "Not_A Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  --compressed
```

So, where can I see the actual request body, or how to generate Curl command for the same request?

I have created some server apps, to track uploaded data server-side. In this situation described above, I get all data correctly on server. But there are situations when I don't get it right on server and I want to analyze it on client-side.

Comment: Try `chrome://net-export`

Comment: @wOxxOm there was no additional info. Actually, on the contrary. There was even no request headers.

Comment: Then a middleware like Fiddler, Charles, Wireshark.

Comment: I have avoided so far network level debugging (read: few experience)